Fedora 40 freezes on my thinkpad t460 when chrome is being is used
So,basically the title. Although I am not 100% sure but it happens when:
I am using a browser ( happened both on firefox and chrome)
and the system has been woken up from the sleep/suspend.
Earlier I had system freeze issue due to keyboard (hardware related) , so got it replaced.
Please help. I don't know if it is caused by chrome/firefox or suspend/sleep or some driver issue or some issue in fedora 40 itself.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Use free and swapon to see if you have swap space. You need at least a RAM-sized swap area.
